# Server Push technique with WCF for pushing data to clients

Tags: c#, wcf, chat

How can i use Server Push with my WCF web service to communicate with the asp.net clients and push the data to the browser? Can i implement [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/tech/bosh.shtml) with WCF?

Thank you.

NLV

Comment: I answered a similar question a while back... Full working example on github https://github.com/codeplanner/XSocketsWCF A while since this was asked... But still ;) Regards
Uffe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sample [here](http://pokein.com/Help/Samples.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Hi
You can use the attached example I have made.
If you sent it to be a public push server - i.e available via WebService - you will have to add a webservice that will use the MSMQ.
The problem is that you will need to have an IIS installed on both the server and the client.
If you use it internally then MSMQ will be enough.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WcfMsmqServerPush.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative is [signalR](http://signalr.net/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.